# Checkbox preference

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose i have a checkbox prefernce in my preferences of android app which asks user if he wants to put a lock on app and when we click on it asks for credentials by opening a dialog. Now question is if it this point the app crashes (by force closing or by pressing home key and then removing it from recent apps) the checkbox prefernce remain checked and it puts a lock on my application because when we click on checkbox prefernce the checkboxpreferncechanged() is fired and it gets checked. So how could i avoid it? I have created that dialog inside checkboxpreferncechanged() event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not change the preference until the dialog returns successfully.

E.g.:

```
checkBoxPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, final Object newValue) {
    if (!(newValue instanceof Boolean)) return false;

    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Check if credentials ok and save the preference
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            prefs.edit()
                .putBoolean("CHECKBOX", (Boolean) newValue)
                .commit();
          }
        });
    // By returning false we don't update the preference
    return false;
  }
});
```